# Cross-browser event handlers, jQuery not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I bet that this is simple but I have had no luck so far. I want to add event handlers in cross-browser cross-version way. That's my code

```
if ($.browser.msie) {
  if ($(p)[0].addEventListener) {
    $(p)[0].addEventListener("mousedown", function () { OnMouseDown(); }, true);
    $(p)[0].addEventListener("mouseup", function () { OnMouseUp(); }, true);
    $(p)[0].addEventListener("mouseout", function () { OnMouseOut(); }, true);
  } else if ($(p)[0].attachEvent) {
    //ie 11 in compatibility mode hits here but not assign events (checked in developer tools(f12)) 
    $(p)[0].attachEvent("onmousedown", function () { OnMouseDown(); });
    $(p)[0].attachEvent("onmouseup", function () { OnMouseUp(); });
    $(p)[0].attachEvent("onmouseout", function () { OnMouseOut(); });
  }
} else {
  //this works fine in newer ie and in "normal" mode
  $(p).mousedown(OnMouseDown);
  $(p).mouseup(OnMouseUp);
  $(p).mouseout(OnMouseOut);
}
```

Has anyone any ideas? jQuery not working in compatibility mode.

Comment: Which version of jquery you tried to use?

Comment: Version 1.4.2. It's old project

Comment: I wonder why are you binding events like this _while_ you're using jQuery. Or why you're using jQuery if you like to bind event handlers like this. Also, $.browser has been removed from jQuery.

Comment: I don't understand, you have checked the IE browser in 1st if condition and you are saying that in else block is working fine for IE newer version, but else will be called when browser is other that IE. Could you please explain it.

Comment: $.browser working fine:)  I want to use attachEvent because ie 11 in comaptibility mode (which mimic 7 or 8 ie , i dont really know),  jQuery doesn't want to work

Comment: Initially i thought that $.browser will be true for all ies but is false for newer more standard compliant

Answer (score 1):

Why not just attach events with .bind (I see that its and older version of jQuery)?

Do something like:

```
$(p).bind('mousedown', OnMouseDown);
$(p).bind('mouseup', OnMouseup);
$(p).bind('mouseout', OnMouseOut);
```

**EDIT**: well, if this does not work, $.browser also has a "version" property and you can treat newer IE like other browsers. Check [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gSDvf/)

anyway, try not to user browser related code anyway. Take a look at a library that does that for you: [Modernizer](http://modernizr.com/)

Comment: Alas, not working. I wonder , it is possible that attachEvent doesn't work because i want to set it via $("p")[0] or maybe reason is that i later append it to other dom element and that element to another